# Bootstrap carousel not working properly - formatting strange

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

Ignore the smooth scrolling for now, I haven't put into effect.
I have created a bootstrap carousel for some images and it just doesn't look right; the formatting is all over the place. If anyone knows what's wrong it would be greatly appreciated

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
      <title> Home </title>

      <head>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
          <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
        </head>

      <body>

        <span id="backtotop">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-default-top" >
          <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
                    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
                   </a>
            </div>
                  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                        <li><a href="index.html"> Home </a>
                        </li>
                            <li><a href="aboutus.html"> About me </a>
                            </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="login.html" id="a2"> Contact </a>
                        </li>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </nav>
        </span> 


        <span id="backtotop">
           <div class="jumbotron" id="jumbotron-1">
              <div class="container text-left" >
                 <h1>Hello.</h1>
                 <BR>
                    <p>Welcome to my porfolio website.</p>
                    <p id="gray">This page is a showcase of my web development skills.</p>
                    <a data-scroll href="#languages">Languages</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div> 
        </span>



        <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-12">

                      <div id="my slider"  class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel"> 

                          <!-- indicators dot nov -->
                          <!-- wrapper for slides -->

                          <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                              <div class="item active"> 
                                  <img src="https://www.gaslampmedia.com/media/bootstrap.png" alt="Bootstrap"/>

                                  <div class="carousel-caption">
                                      <h1>Bootstrap</h1>
                                  </div>

                              </div>
                          </div>
                          <!-- controls (next and prev buttons) -->
                      </div>
               </div>
         </div>
      </div>

        <!-- <span id="languages">
              <div class="jumbotron" id="jumbotron-language">
                  <div class="container text-left">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">   
                 </div>
               <h2>Languages/Frameworks I have experience with</h2>
               <hr>
                  <p>HTML(5)</p>
                   <a href="http://getbootstrap.com"><p>Bootstrap</p></a>
                   <p>CSS(3)</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
        </span>
         -->


        <div class="container" align="right" id="backtotopcontainer">
              <div class="col-lg-6">
                <a data-scroll href="#backtotop" id="backtotop">Back to top</a>
            </div>
        </div>

            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <script src="dist/js/smooth-scroll.js"></script>
      </body>

        <script>
        smoothScroll.init();
        </script>

        <script>
          $(document).ready(function(){
            $(window).scroll(function() { // check if scroll event happened
              if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) { // check if user scrolled more than 50 from top of the browser window
                $(".navbar-fixed-top").css("background-color", "#000"); // if yes, then change the color of class "navbar-fixed-top" to white (#f8f8f8)
                $(".navbar.navbar-default .nav > li > #a2").css("color:#000, #a2"); // if yes, then change the color of class "navbar-fixed-top" to white (#f8f8f8)

              } else {
                $(".navbar-fixed-top").css("background-color", "transparent"); // if not, change it back to transparent
              }
            });
          });
       </script>
      </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that will solve your problem, but you added a space instead of an underscore in "my slider", thus having 2 ID's.